# Did I understood Uniswap's `amountSpecifiedRemaining` correctly?

Tags: solidity, dapps, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

I am following uniswapV3 development book. I have a confusion from one of its [chapters](https://uniswapv3book.com/docs/milestone_2/generalize-swapping/#filling-orders).

The struct is:

```
struct SwapState {
    uint256 amountSpecifiedRemaining;
    uint256 amountCalculated;
    uint160 sqrtPriceX96;
    int24 tick;
}
```

I am confused with **amountSpecifiedRemaining**, I am explaining what did I understand, tell me if I am wrong:
It tracks the remaining amount of tokens that needs to be bought by the pool means suppose a user wanna sell 10 ETH in a swap, so it tracks how many token the user is selling, like 10 eth, 9 eth, 8 eth .... etc. So when it becomes 0 then swap is done.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

**amountSpecifiedRemaining** represents the remaining amount of tokens the user wants to swap. It decreases as the swap progresses until it reaches 0, indicating the swap is complete. **amountCalculated** represents the amount of the other token the user will receive in exchange for their tokens. **sqrtPriceX96** and **tick** are used to calculate the price and amount of the other token received in the swap, based on a unique pricing model used by Uniswap V3 protocol